# How to make a chrome extension that disables redirection?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When I make a request to https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81397375/test.html I get this response back:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location ="https://www.google.com/";
</script>
</html>
```

How can I create a chrome extension that will prevent the redirect? **In other words I will like to remove all scripts In other words I want to end up with:**

```
<html>

</html>
```

---

**This is what I have tried so far:**

part of manifest.json

```
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "https://*/*test.html*" ],
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "all_frames": true,
            "js": [ "script.js" ]
        }
  ],
```

script.js:

```
 function doBeforeLoad(event) {
    debugger;
    var doc = event.srcElement;
    doc.head.remove(); // remove entire header!
    //if (event.srcElement.tagName == "SCRIPT") {
        //event.preventDefault();
    //}
}

document.addEventListener('beforeload', doBeforeLoad, true);
```

The script executes but for some reason the page is still redirected :/

Comment: There's no way to prevent script execution in chrome using normal means. You can do what uBlock extra does: download the current page URL via XHR, parse it, strip scripts, overwrite current page using document.open+write+close

Comment: Try disabling JavaScript on that URL using chrome.contentSettings API.